# SpeedBoost when you collect X items in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, unity-game-engine, syntax-error

I would like to code that when my player collects 5 items (so when paintCount = 5), the player gets a speedboost for a short period of time and the counter goes back to zero. But I can't even figure out how to get my player goes faster. It gives an error when I want to multiplie the speed variable with 2. Any help is welcome (in c#).

The speed variable is in my main script for my players movement.

the error:
"Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await and new object expressions can be used as a statement."

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Paintser : PowerUp
{

  public static int paintCount = 0; 

  public void SpeedUp()
  {
    if (paintCount == 5)
    {
      SimplePlayer0.speed * 2;

    }
  }
}
```

The other class:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PowerUp : MonoBehaviour
{

  void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
  {
    if (other.tag == "Player")
    {
      Destroy(this.gameObject);
      Paintser.paintCount++;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SimplePlayer0.speed * 2;
```

This is not a valid assignment, it is just a multiplication, which can not stand by its own. You need to use

```
SimplePlayer0.speed = SimplePlayer0.speed * 2;
```

Or

```
SimplePlayer0.speed *= 2;
```

Both of these equivalently mean: multiply `SimplePlayer0.speed` with `2` and assign the result back to `SimplePlayer0.speed`.

Comment: Thank you , I totally forgot about that! But when I use it now, it wont go faster. Although there are no errors.

Comment: Pleasure! About your second problem: a) there's too little information in your question to answer that and b) it is not good practise to ask new questions within a question/comment. Ask a new question, providing relevant information.

Answer (score 3):

Do `SimplePlayer0.speed *= 2` to resolve your compilation error.

In your code, you simply multiplied SimplePlayer0.speed by 2, but didn't assign it to anything.  What you put was simply interpreted as such: Get the value of `SimplyPlayer0.speed` and multiply it by two.  It doesn't save the *result of the calculation* as the new value for `SimplyPlayer0.speed`.

Comment: I just wanted to write exact same answer. :D